# Reading javascript file into Node as command line arguments and parsing it

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, npm, acorn

I'm writing an npm module that needs to take a configuration file as command line arguments. Currently I have it working with a json file like so:

```
const configurationObject = JSON.parse(await readFile(argv.configPath, 'utf8'));
```

With this I can run my module like so:

```
myModule --configPath "./source/to/config.json"
```

Now I would like to do the same, but using a .js file as the configuration file.

How do I parse that file and store the resulting object to a variable? I've looked into the npm package  `acorn`, but parsing with acorn just gives me an AST, but I can figure out how to turn that into executable code?

```
// This results in a string containing the js file contents
// (readFile is fs.readFile wrapped in a Promise)
const fileInput = await readFile(argv.configPathJs, 'utf8');

// Gives me an object structure breaking down the code into an AST
acorn.parse(fileInput, {ecmaVersion: 2020});
```

Comment: Any reason not to `import` or `require` the config file?

Comment: Is there a reliable way I can do so, when the code you see above is in an npm package and the config file would reside in the project consuming that package?

Comment: You're using `argv.configPathJs` above. Is that not usable?

Comment: @funkylaundry Just use `require(process.cwd() + "/config.js");`